# how to make additional flat tables columns search in catalogsearch_fulltext?

Tags: magento-1.9, catalogsearch

It is required to make additional custom tables ( custom created flat models) search, based on basic search query, if filter input box is checked at the layered filter navigation.

If this was persistent requirement I would override `_prepareProductIndex` of `Mage_CatalogSearch_Model_Resource_Fulltext` in my module, to add data from my custom tables into index, but this is optional requirement, and I wonder, how to patch the search query properly ?

I came up with idea to register custom value in `Mage::registry` in custom filter, and if it exists, make modification to the search query.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was required to override `Mage_CatalogSearch_Model_Resource_Fulltext` and simply add some `where` conditions in `prepareResult` method.

Also I have added specific flat table check column in `catalogsearch_query` and used it to proper selecting of query in overridden `Mage_CatalogSearch_Model_Resource_Query::loadByQuery` method.

So if the filter is on, it sets the column value in `prepareResult` and saving it, and selecting from `catalogsearch_query` in `loadByQuery` by the value of column (filter status).